# How to "denormalize" data frame/make one column from many binary columns

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a data frame with many binary columns that indicate if a specific product name was mentioned. I want to create a single column that lists all those specific product names with a 1 for that row.

For simplicity, let's say this is my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': [1,0,0], 'Another Name': [0,1,1], 'Different Name':[0,0,1]})
```

I want to create this column:

```
0 ['Name']
1 ['Another Name']
2 ['Another Name','Different Name']
```

My thought process is to iterate through each row, and if there is a 1 for any name, add that to the list for the column

```
namelist = list()
if df['Name']==1:
    namelist.append("Name")
else if df['Another Name']==1:
    namelist.append("Another Name")
else if df['Different Name']==1:
    namelist.append("Different Name")
```

But this wouldn't keep the list specific to the row. Suggestions on how to do this?

My solution: I used the logic from G. Anderson' solution, but I needed to specify the columns of interest, rather than all in the data frame. I'm sure there's a better way of doing this than I what I ended up doing, but this is what I did:

```
df['Name']=df['Name'].replace({1:'Name',0:''})
df['Another Name']=df['Another Name'].replace({1:'Another Name',0:''})
df['Different Name']=df['Different Name'].replace({1:'Different Name',0:''})

df['Product Name']=df['Name'] + df['Another Name'] + df['Different Name']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my shot:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': (1,0,0), 'Another Name': [0,1,1], 'Different Name':[0,0,1]})

    Name    Another Name    Different Name
0   1       0               0
1   0       1               0
2   0       1               1
```

Replace the values with either the column name or `''`

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col]=df[col].replace({1:col,0:''})

    Name    Another Name    Different Name
0   Name        
1           Another Name    
2           Another Name    Different Name
```

Add a column that's a list of the other column values

```
df['new_col']=df.iloc[:,:].apply(lambda x: [i for i in list(x) if i], axis=1)

    Name    Another Name    Different Name  new_col
0   Name                                    [Name]
1           Another Name                    [Another Name]
2           Another Name    Different Name  [Another Name, Different Name]
```

Remove the other columns

```
df=df['new_col']

0                            [Name]
1                    [Another Name]
2    [Another Name, Different Name]
Name: new_col, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

(Note that I added a row so the dataframe wasn't square to help me make sure of correctness)

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': [1,0,0,0], 'Another Name': [0,1,1,0], 'Different Name':[0,0,1,1]})

df = pd.melt(df.mul(1+df.index,axis=0))
[(i, list(df[df.value==i].variable)) for i in set(df[df.value>0].value)]

[(1, ['Name']),
 (2, ['Another Name']),
 (3, ['Another Name', 'Different Name']),
 (4, ['Different Name'])]
```

Comment: Ha - I was just thinking your solution was pretty slick!  Nicely done!

Comment: Thank you for your help, G. Anderson an dkeithpjolley. My data frame actually has many other columns besides the binary "name" columns, and so I would need to specify exactly which columns to apply the melt or replace. I had trouble doing that, so I ended up using the logic from G. Anderson's solution, but applied it in a more manual way.